# How is the "light" trap at the beginning supposed to work?

Tags: realism, indiana-jones, raiders-of-the-lost-ark

In the opening scene of *Raiders of the Lost Ark*, Indiana Jones encounters a trap where blocking a shaft of light with his hand causes spikes to shoot out of the wall next to him:

This always bugged me, as such a trap would probably require some kind of light sensor, which would be far too advanced for an ancient civilization to create.

Is there any plausible explanation for how this trap could work?

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/109013/ancient-light-trigger-mechanism

Comment: This might be considered related to the Advanced Ancient Humans trope.  I mean, in theory the trap would be sprung at nightfall every day, but they may have accounted for that and figured out a way to reset it.  Which is why you see Forrester's skeleton stuck to it.

Comment: Unfortunately no explanation is given in the movie or in the screenplay. Thus any answers would be speculative at best. I'm reluctant to close as Opinion Based but I suspect that is in fact the case.

Comment: Are you expecting logic in a movie full of mythical elements ?

Comment: Of course the light trap is the most obviously impossible one, but if we really investigated I’m sure we’d find all of them are wildly implausible at best. Especially after having aged for centuries. Another good question is where did they find or how could they make a boulder so close to spherical? Or how did they compress the air for the blow darts? How did they keep centuries of rain from seeping in and filling up the pit right next to the huge stone door that somehow drops veeeery slowly? How is it possible that Forrestal is the only corpse in the place?

Comment: @Rahul In the cases that would require logic for the suspension of disbelief, yes.
The powers of the ark are a part of the "contract" I make with the movie. That's something fantastic in the meaning that something extraordinary occurs in an "ordinary" world. However, the rest (including the temple from the beginning) is treated as something ordinary (with triggers, mechanisms...), as part of the world, so a "shut up its magic" won't be satisfying for my suspension of disbelief. :)

Comment: @ToddWilcox Ok, but for those other traps we have explanations (there are physical mechanisms) despite the question of the durability of the traps being odd.

Comment: Another question- how'd Indy figure out the trap but Forrestall just blundered into it if he was as good as Indy believed him to be?

Comment: There's no help in the novelisation. Indy trips a fairly mundane pressure sensor trap; 
*"He bent down, felt around on the floor, found a thick stalk of a weed, hauled it out—then reached forward and tossed the stalk into the chamber. For a split second nothing happened. And then there was a faint whirring noise, a creaking sound, and the walls of the chamber seemed to break open as giant metal spikes, like the jaws of some impossible shark, slammed together..."*

Comment: @kingofpanes - Finely honed instincts: "*He continued to gaze toward the chamber, his mind already working, figuring, his imagination helping him to think his way inside the minds of the people who had built this place so long ago. They would want to protect the treasure of the Temple, he thought. They would want to erect barricades, traps, to make sure no stranger ever reached the heart of the Temple. He moved closer to the entrance now, moving with the instinctive caution of the hunter who smells danger on the downwind, who feels peril before he can see signs of it.*